# Why is SearchExecutor returning results in inconsistent formats and what can I do about it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, search, search-results, file

I use the following method to find `List<File>` on our SharePoint site:

```
    private async Task<List<File>> FindAsync(ClientContext clientContext, KeywordQuery keywordQuery)
    {
        ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = new SearchExecutor(clientContext)
            .ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

        List<File> files = new List<File>();
        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
        {
            File file = GetFromPath(clientContext, resultRow["Path"].ToString());
            files.Add(file);
        }
        return files;
    }

    private File GetFromPath(ClientContext clientContext, string path)
    {
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        List list = web.GetListByTitle(_sharePointConfig.DocumentsRoot);

        int parameterIndex = path.IndexOf('?');
        string query = parameterIndex >= 0 
            ? path[parameterIndex..] 
            : "";
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection queryParts = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(query);
        string id = queryParts.Get("ID");
        ListItem item = list.GetItemById(id);
        return item.File;                
    }
```

This works as expected on a Sharepoint site we created specifically so I would not be testing against production data.

However, when I then swapped the siteUrl to reference the production site -- hosted on exactly the same instance of SharePoint Online, with the same SharePoint online subdomain -- this failed.

Whereas the developer site would return Urls like

> https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/DevelopementTestingSite/Shared Documents/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=43

on the production site, I get back Urls like:

> "https://example.sharepoint.com/sites/Mietkundenseite2/Freigegebene Dokumente/Alle Mietantrag Enpal/von Angenommen ab Mai.2019/20190605_Weiss_11_Mietantrag.pdf"

Because this URL does not contain the ID, the method fails.

Is there a way I can ensure that I always get back the format with the Id?

Alternatively, is there a way I can use the production format to get the corresponding File value?

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a work-around, and arguably a better solution, than an answer to the actual question:

```
    private async Task<List<File>> FindAsync(ClientContext clientContext, KeywordQuery keywordQuery)
    {
        ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = new SearchExecutor(clientContext)
            .ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
        await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();

        List<File> files = new List<File>();
        foreach (IDictionary<string, object> resultRow in results.Value[0].ResultRows)
        {
            Guid uniqueId = Guid.Parse(resultRow["UniqueId"].ToString());
            files.Add(GetByUniqueId(clientContext, uniqueId));
        }
        return files;
    }

    private File GetByUniqueId(ClientContext clientContext, Guid uniqueId)
    {
        File file = clientContext.Web.GetFileById(uniqueId);
        clientContext.Load(file, f => f.Name);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        return file;                
    }
```

Comment: While I no longer need the answer to my original question, for the sake of curiousity -- and because I can't accept my own answer yet anyway -- I leave this question open (for now).